# Reg export works differently among "service" and "administrator"

Tags: batch-file, registry

I tried "reg export" command in the script below

```
reg export "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" xxx.reg
```

but the script work different action when it is worked by administrator or service.
(When it is worked service(user is "nt authority\SYSTEM"), xxx.reg's registry is few than by admin)

I want to know how to get same registry by both "service" and "admin"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Administrator and service account are different accounts with different user hives. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is merely a shortcut to `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-...` where `S-1-5-21-...` is the SID of the current user. If you want a task running under a service account to export data from another user's hive, you need to load that hive into the registry first and unload it afterwards:

```
reg load HKU\Temp C:\Users\username\ntuser.dat
reg export "HKU\Temp\Control Panel\Desktop" xxx.reg
reg unload HKU\Temp
```

You may also need to adjust permissions on the profile folders, because by default only the profile owner (i.e. the respective user) has access to a profile.