# Get remote registry for logged in user

Tags: powershell, registry

I have seen many examples on the net about getting remote registry but I want to check the folder redirection for logged in users not the user I run the script as.

Is this even possible using PowerShell? Before I joined this company their IT was outsourced and the whole AD/GPO everything is a big big mess. Some users are redirecting and some are not so I want to check who has the redirection enabled without having to go to each computer physically.

```
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('CurrentUser','10.0.0.113')
$regkey = $reg.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\User Shell Folders")
$regkey.GetValue("Personal")
```

I tried this but again only shows me information about the admin user account that the script runs as.

Comment: In this scenario i think you'd wanna look in peoples NTUser.dat (that hkey current user for that user) then it doesnt matter who is logged on at that moment. http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/modifying-the-registry-of-another-user/  Do know, i think its best that the user is not logged on at that moment, or that you make a copy of the NTUser.dat

Comment: Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013466/loading-ntuser-dat-with-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but would require [finding out who is currently logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34502571/1630171), then [loading their `ntuser.dat` file into the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18720660/1630171).

```
$computer = '...'
$qry = 'SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name="explorer.exe"'
$key = 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders'

$username = (Get-WmiObject -Computer $computer -Query $qry).GetOwner().User

Invoke-Command -Computer $computer -ScriptBlock {
  & reg load "HKU\foo C:\Users\$using:username\ntuser.dat" | Out-Null
  (Get-ItemProperty "HKU:\foo\$using:key").Personal
  & reg unload 'HKU\foo' | Out-Null
}
```

A simpler approach might be using a logon script to write the information to a file (either on the user's computer or a central share), so you can collect the information from there:

```
$key    = 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders'
$output = "\\server\share\$env:USERNAME.txt"

Get-ItemProperty "HKCU:\$key" | Select-Object -Expand Personal |
  Set-Content $output
```